# write a wrapper function to download csv data with data from different tabels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the csv creation function I have written in `order.rb`

```
  def self.to_csv(column_names)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |order|
        csv << order.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

I have written the following in the controller, i.e in `orders` controller.

```
def csv_downloader
    start_date=params[:class_start_date]
    end_date=params[:class_end_date]
    if start_date.to_date<=end_date.to_date
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:data]="orders_customs_display"
        column_names=["created_at","order_legacy_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","clip_status","total","perf_cut","c4u_cut"]
        format.csv { send_data Order.customs_not_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).select("created_at","order_legacy_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","clip_status","total","perf_cut","c4u_cut").to_csv(column_names) }
        elsif params[:data]="orders_customs_refunded"
        column_names=["created_at","order_legacy_id","performer_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","total"]  
        format.csv { send_data Order.customs_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).select("created_at","order_legacy_id","performer_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","total").to_csv(column_names) }
        elsif params[:data]="orders_white_label_display"
        column_names=["created_at","orderrder_legacy_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","clip_status","total","perf_cut","c4u_cut"]
        format.csv { send_data Order.white_label_not_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).to_csv }
        elsif params[:data]="orders_white_label_refunded"
        format.csv { send_data Order.white_label_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).to_csv }
        elsif params[:data]="orders_affiliate_display"
        format.csv { send_data Order.affiliate_not_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).to_csv }
        else
        format.csv { send_data Order.affiliate_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).to_csv }
      end
    end
    else
        redirect_to orders_path,:notice=>"Start date should be higher than end date or equal"
    end
  end
```

As you can see this line selects the columns I want in the table with the respective column name and prints them into a csv.

```
column_names=["created_at","order_legacy_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","clip_status","total","perf_cut","c4u_cut"]
format.csv { send_data Order.customs_not_refunded.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date.to_date,end_date.to_date).select("created_at","order_legacy_id","clip_category_id","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","clip_status","total","perf_cut","c4u_cut").to_csv(column_names) }
```

Now the problem is I have clip_category_id which is nothing but a column associated with the order table. I want to be able to access the column `name` in the `clip_category` table and then print that in the table instead of the id alone. Is there a way to do this?

---

I tried the following

```
Order.customs_not_refunded.joins(:clip_category).where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?","1-10-2013".to_date,DateTime.now.to_date).select("created_at","order_legacy_id","name","duration_id","quality_id","delivery_time_id","clip_status","total","perf_cut","c4u_cut")
```

To get the following error:

```
Order Load (0.7ms)  SELECT created_at, order_legacy_id, name, duration_id, quality_id, delivery_time_id, clip_status, total, perf_cut, c4u_cut FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "clip_categories" ON "clip_categories"."id" = "orders"."clip_category_id" WHERE "orders"."payment_status" = 't' AND "orders"."refunded" = 'f' AND (created_at BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-12') ORDER BY created_at DESC
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT created_at, order_legacy_id, name, duration_id, quality_id, delivery_time_id, clip_status, total, perf_cut, c4u_cut FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "clip_categories" ON "clip_categories"."id" = "orders"."clip_category_id" WHERE "orders"."payment_status" = 't' AND "orders"."refunded" = 'f' AND (created_at BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-12')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT created_at, order_legacy_id, name, duration_id, quality_id, delivery_time_id, clip_status, total, perf_cut, c4u_cut FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "clip_categories" ON "clip_categories"."id" = "orders"."clip_category_id" WHERE "orders"."payment_status" = 't' AND "orders"."refunded" = 'f' AND (created_at BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-12')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

---

I tried the following

```
Order.customs_not_refunded.joins(:clip_category).where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?","1-10-213".to_date,DateTime.now.to_date).select("orders.created_at")
```

And got the following

```
    Order Load (98.6ms)  SELECT orders.created_at FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "clip_categories" ON "clip_categories"."id" = "orders"."clip_category_id" WHERE "orders"."payment_status" = 't' AND "orders"."refunded" = 'f' AND (created_at BETWEEN '0213-10-01' AND '2013-11-12') ORDER BY created_at DESC
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT orders.created_at FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "clip_categories" ON "clip_categories"."id" = "orders"."clip_category_id" WHERE "orders"."payment_status" = 't' AND "orders"."refunded" = 'f' AND (created_at BETWEEN '0213-10-01' AND '2013-11-12')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT orders.created_at FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "clip_categories" ON "clip_categories"."id" = "orders"."clip_category_id" WHERE "orders"."payment_status" = 't' AND "orders"."refunded" = 'f' AND (created_at BETWEEN '0213-10-01' AND '2013-11-12')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

---

Update 3

```
Order.customs_not_refunded.joins(:clip_category).where("orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?","1-10-213".to_date,DateTime.now.to_date)
```

This works without error. How do I get particular colums alone from both the tables. Say `created_at` column from order and `name` column from clip_category_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using this

```
Order.customs_not_refunded.joins(:clip_category).joins(:delivery_time).joins(:quality).joins(:duration).where("orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?","1-10-213".to_date,DateTime.now.to_date).select("orders.*,clip_categories.name AS category,qualities.name AS quality,durations.time AS duration,delivery_times.duration AS delivery_time")
```

Answer (score 0):

created_at is in both tables. in your where() call, prefix created_at with the one you're filtering on, e.g. orders.created_at or clip_categories.created_at.

Comment: You need to specify it in the where() call, too, not just the select call. Basically, anywhere you refer to a field name that is in both tables you need to specify which you need in that context.

Comment: Please see the new update. Using the `orders.created_at` inside the where also put out a similar error. But without the last select call it seems to work without error but the expected output is a bit different.